# Creating an array of student, and using the values

Tags: java, arrays

What I'm trying to do:

Enter number from 1 to 5

1. To quit program
2. To add details to an array of 4 Student (ID, name, assignment_mark1, assignment_mark2, examination)
3. To output details of student
4. To compute and output average overall mark for student (assignment_mark1, assignment_mark2, examination) / 3
5. To input student ID and display input student details

I can't use an array list

#### My object class:

```
 public class Student{
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 private String name;
 private int ID;
 private float assignment_mark1;
 private float assignment_mark2;
 private float examination;

 StudentDetail(){ //default constructor
 this.name= "default";
 this.ID =0;
 this.assignment_mark1 = 0;
 this.assignment_mark2 = 0;
 this.examination = 0;
 }

 Student(String name, int ID, float assignment_mark1, float 
assignment_mark2, 
 float examination){   
 this.name = name;
 this.ID= ID;
 this.assignment_mark1= assignment_mark1;
 this.assignment_mark2 = assignment_mark2;
 this.examination = examination;

 }

  /*
 get and set methods here
  */

 quit(){ //quit program }

 addDetailsToAllStudent();  

 outputAllDetails();

 computeAverageMarks(double assignment1, double assignment2, double 
examination, double practical_work) {  
 double total=0;
total = (assignment1 + assignment2 + examination) / 3.0;
return  total;

 displayStudentDetail();
```

#### Static class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


  Student[] array = new Student[4];//
  boolean isRunning = true;
  int choice = 0;
  while(isRunning){

      System.out.println("1. Quit ");
      System.out.println("2. Add  Details to all students ");
      System.out.println("3. Output all student details");
      System.out.println("4. compute average student marks");
      System.out.println("5. Display student details based on ID");
      choice = keyboard.nextInt();

   while(choice>0 && choice<=5)
   {
      if (choice == 1)  //quit
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
      else if (choice == 2) //Add  Details to all students
      { 

          for(int i=0; i< array.length ; i++)
         {
          array[i] = new StudentDetail();

          System.out.println("enter student"+(i +1) +":");

           System.out.println("name");
          String first_name = keyboard.nextLine();
          array[i].setName(name);


           System.out.println("Student id");
          int ID= keyboard.nextInt();
          array[i].setStudent_id(ID);


           System.out.println("get Assignment1");
          int getAssignment1 = keyboard.nextInt();
          array[i].setAssignment1(getAssignment1);

           System.out.println("get Assignment2 ");
          int getAssignment2 = keyboard.nextInt();
          array[i].setAssignment2(getAssignment2);

       System.out.println("get Examination");
          int getExamination = keyboard.nextInt();
          array[i].setExamination(getExamination);
    }
   }

     else if (choice == 3) //Output all student details
       {
           for(int i=0; i< array.length ; i++)
          {
              System.out.println(array[i].getName());
              System.out.println(array[i].getStudent_id());
              System.out.println(array[i].getAssignment1());
              System.out.println(array[i].getAssignment2());
              System.out.println(array[i].getExamination());
          }
      }

      else if (choice == 4) //compute average student marks
      {
         for(int i=0; i< array.length ; i++)
         {
         double temp = array[i].getAssignment1();
         double temp2=  array[i].getAssignment2();
         double temp3= array[i].getPractical_work();
         double temp4 =  array[i].getExamination();


         System.out.println(array[i].averageOverallMark(temp, 
           temp2,temp3,temp4));
         }
      }
      else if (choice == 5) // Display student details based on ID
      {
          numberOfStudentAchieveMark();
      }
```

My questions:

1. Normally when creating an object I would do something like this:    "Student std1 = new Student();"
   Then if I want to run method quit(), it would be std1.quit();
   however, since I'm creating an array, how would I run the method quit() or any other methods;

------------- SOLVED -------------------

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask becuse you are making multiple questions in the same place, also you can check the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site

Comment: School assignment from Murdoch university?

Answer (score 0):

For your question 1: You can array[i].getName() as above.
For your question 2: since you used private float for assignment scores. You need to complete your getter and setter.
For your question 3: After you create your setting in step 2, you can call that setter on a Student object you create in static class.